# Deploy Azure WebJob using VSTS

Tags: visual-studio, azure, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-webjobs

I'm having some issues deploying an Azure WebJob using Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS).

**The WebJob seems to be deployed successfully but it breaks the Azure website that is hosted in the same App Service!** I don't have this problem if I deploy using VS2013.

This is my build task that generates the WebJob deployment package:

[image: Build task - generate Azure WebJob deployment package]

And this is my deployment task:

[image: Deploy WebJob task]

There are no errors when I deploy the Azure WebJob. If I go to the Azure Portal I see the WebJob is there, and it runs successfully. WebJob files are copied into the `wwwroot\App_Data\jobs\triggered\RemoveExpiredDids` folder as expected, but the problem is that some other files will be copied into the `wwwroot\App_Data\bin` folder, which will break the existing website that was already deployed into that App Service!!!

So I decided to find out why this was happening. After downloading and extracting the deployment package I saw there are 2 folders (`app_data` and `bin`) and the scheduler file (`settings.job`):

[image: WebJob deployment package]

This explains why some assemblies are coppied into the `wwwroot\App_Data\bin` of the App Service. The strange thing is that this doesn't happen when deploying from VS2013!!! I took a look into the MSBuild log and found the following line:

> Object dirPath ([app service name]\bin) skipped due to skip directive 'SkipBinFolderOnDeploy'.

Concluding, `bin` folder is included when deploying the Azure WebJob from VSTS but is excluded when deploying it from VS2013.

So my question is: **how to prevent the `bin` folder from being deployed when using VSTS?** Is there any MSBuild parameter/flag to do this?

Comment: Do you solve it with my solution?

Comment: I haven't had the opportunity to try it yet @starain-MSFT, I got "stuck" in bureaucratic issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to these ways to deploy webjob to azure:

1. Modify Visual Studio Build task to deploy webjob with **FileSystem** (MSBuild Arguments: `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\WebJob" /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish`)
2. Add Delete Files task to release definition to delete bin folder (Source Folder: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/WebJobVnext/drop/WebJob`); Contents:`bin`)
3. Modify Azure App Service Deploy task (1. Uncheck **Publish using Web Deploy** option. 2. Package or folder: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/[artifact name] /drop/WebJob`)

Comment: Thanks @starain-MSFT, I'll give it a try when I can.

Comment: Feel free to post the result here after you trying.

Comment: I finally had the opportunity to try to fix this, thanks @starain-MSFT. I had to do some minor changes, as described in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I've had issue with this particular problem as well.

The latest method I found is using [Web Deploy Operation Settings](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089(v=ws.10).aspx) , -skip:Directory= (in this case it would be -skip:Directory='\\bin') when you create your azure deploy task in the release definition (Additional arguments). I've seen that this indeed excludes the bin folder from the update actions ([result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdNMK.png)).

Let me know if this helps you in any way.

Comment: Thanks @vlad-apetre, good to know that. I was able to sort it out, anyway. BTW v3 of task "Azure App Service Deploy" doesn't have the option to specify extra parameters.

Comment: @RuiJarimba Funny, I'm sure it's on v3 I made the changes myself. In any case, I'm glad you managed to sort it out. All the best.

Comment: @RuiJarimba, You only get the option in the v3 task when you select the option "Publish using Web Deploy". You then get an extra field called "Additional arguments". The value `-skip:Directory='\\bin'` works.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to fix it, thanks @starain-MSFT for pointing me in the right direction. I had to make some minor changes, though. This is the task that creates the deployment package:

[image: Generate Azure WebJob deployment package]

MSBuild arguments:

> /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:Configuration=$(BuildConfiguration) /p:OutputPath=.\bin\  /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\temp\WebJob"

The difference here comparing to @starain-MSFT answer is that I had to add the `/p:OutputPath=` parameter, otherwise I'd get the following error:

> The OutputPath property is not set for project

After generating the package, I delete the `bin` folder and zip it (this reduces the build time).

This is my deployment task:

[image: Deploy Azure WebJob using VSTS]

Please note that `$(DeploymentPackagePath)` is the path to the zip file that contains the deployment package, as mentioned before. It doesn't matter if you deploy the package as a zip file or if you unzip it and deploy the folder, it works both ways.