# How to deploy Azure WebJob as part of automatic VSTS deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-webjobs, webjob

Is there a way of having my Azure WebJob automatically deploy without needing to right click and select "Publish as Azure WebJob" every time? i.e. when I check-in my solution it is automatically deploy to the Azure Portal webjob section

Answer (score 5):

While I tried to accomplish this, I found out that there is no tooling support for dotnet core projects as of now. The proposed webjobs.props/ msbuild solutions are all dotnet framework specific.

However I also found out that a webjob can be anything that's executable on the local machine (could be node.js or just a batch command).

---

The key is to understand how WebJobs are recognized by the host:

- A WebJob on a Windows host is (by what I gathered from experimenting with it) just a `run.cmd` file that contains instructions on how to start the webJob. For dotnet core that would be `dotnet MyDll.dll %*` (`%*` to pass arguments for output redirection etc. down from the host).
- Now depending on wether the job is continuous or triggered the `run.cmd` file needs to be located either at `app_data/jobs/continuous/[NameOfJob]` or `app_data/jobs/triggered/[NameOfJob]`. For the triggered job you could also add a schedule using a `settings.job` file like described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#cron-expressions).
- If there is a `run.cmd` at the proper location it will be recognized as a WebJob

---

**Now to deploy a webjob using VSTS regardless of the runtime framework follow these steps:**

1. Build/Publish your WebJob if necessary to get the executables
2. Add a run.cmd file next to your webjob executables that contains the proper startup instructions. You could also add `settings.job` here if needed.
3. Create the folder hierarchy `app_data/jobs/[triggered/continuous]/[nameOfJob]` and copy your executables into the lowest folder. Make sure `run.cmd` is directly under the `[nameOfJob]/` directory
4. Zip the app_data folder so that the zip-package contains the entire hierarchy
5. Publish your zip file using the normal Azure App Service Deployment task (just like deploying the web app)

And that's it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can.

Brady Gaster has written about this on a [blog post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/enabling-command-line-or-continuous-delivery-of-azure-webjobs/) (haven't tried it myself).

From what I gather, the TL;DR; summary is the following:

> add a file named webjobs.props to the properties folder of the Web Application Project or Console Application you’re publishing

After that, edit the file so the `ManagementCertificate`, `SubscriptionId` and `PublishSettingsPath` are filled with correct data.

Now you should be able to publish the files using the command

```
msbuild WebJobDemo.Web.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=WebJobDemo /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0 /p:Password=asdfasdf
```

(Note, post is written for VS2013)

Afterwards you should see something like this.
[image: deployment output]

You could of course automate this in VSTS (or any other build/deployment tool for that matter) whenever something is checked in to your repository.

A (rather complete) answer on how to do this in VSTS via the command-line can be found in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45703975/352640

Answer (score 3):

You can do it through [Continuous Integration Build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/ci-cd-part-1#enable-continuous-integration-ci) (trigger the build once check in).

Regarding deploy WebJob, you can generate a package through **Visual Studio Build** task with `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.stagingDirectory)"` argument.

Then deploy it through Azure App Deployment task.

More information: [Deploying and Schedule Azure WebJobs from VSTS to Azure Web App](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/05/18/deploying-and-schedule-azure-webjobs-from-vsts-to-azure-web-app-with-bonus-cron-scheduling/)

Answer (score -1):

In Visual Studio in order to enable automatic WebJobs deployment together with a Web project right-click the Web project in Solution Explorer, and then click: Add > Existing Project as Azure WebJob and create your WebJob.

More details can be found in an article by MS - [webjobs-dotnet-deploy-vs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-dotnet-deploy-vs)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22174635)

Comment: I got it and tried to improve the answer. Thanks for feedback.