# Azure CLI - 'az webapp deployment source config-zip' is deleting anothers webjobs

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-webapps

I'm deploying a WebJob using a release pipeline. The pipeline task is being called as follows:

```
- az webapp deployment source config-zip -g <my-resource-group> -n <my-app-service> --src $zipFilePathLocation
```

It happens that when deploying, the other WebJobs that were running on the same resource were Deleted.

Deploying directly through Visual Studio, WebJob rises correctly without deleting the other Jobs.

However, I need to deploy via Azure CLI.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 1):

-By default, Kudu executes the build steps for your Node/.NET application (npm install/donet build). For deployment via Azure DevOps, then the Kudu build is unnecessary. You may disable the Kudu build, create an app setting, `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT`, with a value of `false`- and see if it helps.

-Clear `RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag` (Remove additional files at destination)
With this enabled - it will also remove all files related to any extensions installed on this Azure App Service. To prevent this, set the Exclude files from **App_Data** folder checkbox.

So, essential site **\wwwroot\App_Data\jobs**continuous\testwebjob -ensure that your deployment is not replacing this.

Furthermore, publishing the Web App automatically publishes the WebJob where it belongs. It all happens in a single zip file. Do not try to publish the WebJob project individually once you do that. See this similar [discussion thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50046561/8194837).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best solution, but I was able to solve my problem by creating App Service Slots and deploying each WebJob in a separate Slot.